Why does my FFT output contain extra harmonics?
I made a program in C++ that converts real signal from the time domain into the frequency domain using FFT. I used a Euler's formula to separate calculations for real and imaginary parts of signal. As the result i get odd outputs, where in addition to the correct harmonics, extra harmonics appear.
For example for the input {9, -2.82, -5, 2.82, 1, 2.82, -5, -2.82, 9, -2.82, -5, 2.82, 1, 2.82, -5, -2.82} with 16 elements the result is: {0,0,8,0,40,0,24,0,0,0,24,0,40,0,8,0} when it should be {0,0, 0,40,0,32,0,0,0,32,0,40,0,0,0}. I am stuck at this point. Please help.
Here's my code:
// for example dn = {9, -2.82, -5, 2.82, 1, 2.82, -5, -2.82, 9, -2.82, -5, 2.82, 1, 2.82, -5, -2.82}, kn = 16 is the length of array
printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------Shifted Data--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
float* dm = (float*)malloc(kn * sizeof(float));

uint32_t rev = 0;
uint32_t n = 0;
int order = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < kn; i++) {
    n = i;
    if (!(n & (n - 1)))
        order++;
    for (int j = 0; j < log2(kn); j++) {  // shift input data 
        rev = rev << 1;
        rev = rev | (n & 1);
        n = n >> 1;
    }
//  printf("rev = %d, i = %d order = %d\n", rev, i, order);
//  std::cout << "rev = " << std::bitset<9>(rev) << " i = " << std::bitset<9>(i) <<std::endl;
    dm[i] = dn[rev];
    printf("dm[%d] = %f d[%d] = %f, %d\n\n", i, dm[i], i, dn[i], rev);
    rev = 0;
}

int numselect = kn;
int selectcounter = 0;

while (numselect != 1) {
    numselect = numselect / 2;
    selectcounter++;
}

selectcounter--;
int tempval1 = 0;
int tempval2 = 0;
int tempvalcounter = 0;
int counter = 0;
double **ftnreal = new double* [log2(kn)]; // m*N array for real output
for (int i = 0; i < log2(kn); i++)
    ftnreal[i] = new double[kn];

selectcounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < log2(kn); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < kn; j++)
        ftnreal[i][j] = 0.0;
    if (i == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < kn / 2; j++) {
            ftnreal[i][j * 2] = dm[2 * j] + cos(2 * M_PI * i / 2) * dm[2 * j + 1]; //calculating data for the first column of elements
            ftnreal[i][j * 2 + 1] = dm[2 * j] - cos(2 * M_PI * i / 2) * dm[2 * j + 1];
            printf("ftnreal[%d][%d] = dm[%d] + cos(2 * %f*%d/2)*dm[%d]\n", i, j*2,j*2,M_PI,i,2*j + 1);
            printf("ftnreal[%d][%d] = dm[%d] - cos(2 * %f*%d/2)*dm[%d]\n", i, j * 2 + 1, j * 2, M_PI, i, 2 * j + 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        tempval1 = pow(2, i + 1);
        tempval2 = pow(2, i);
        counter = 0;
        tempvalcounter = 0;
        printf("i = %d, tempval1 = %d, tempval2 = %d\n", i, tempval1, tempval2);
        for (int j = 0; j < kn / 2; j++) {
                ftnreal[i][counter] = ftnreal[i - 1][counter] + cos(2 * M_PI * (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))) * ftnreal[i - 1][counter + tempval2]; //calculating data for the rest of columns
                ftnreal[i][counter + tempval2] = ftnreal[i - 1][counter] - cos(2 * M_PI * (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))) * ftnreal[i - 1][counter + tempval2];
                printf("ftnreal[%d][%d] = ftnreal[%d][%d] + cos(2*%f*(%f/%f))*ftnreal[%d][%d]       / %f      %f\n", i,counter,i - 1,counter,M_PI,float(tempvalcounter), float(tempval1),i - 1,counter + tempval2, float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1), cos(2 * M_PI * (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))));
                printf("ftnreal[%d][%d] = ftnreal[%d][%d] - cos(2*%f*(%f/%f))*ftnreal[%d][%d]       / %f      %f\n", i, counter + tempval2, i - 1, counter, M_PI, float(tempvalcounter), float(tempval1), i - 1, counter + tempval2, float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1), cos(2 * M_PI * (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))));
                counter++;
                tempvalcounter++;
                if (tempvalcounter % tempval2 == 0) {
                    counter = counter + tempval2;
                    tempvalcounter = 0;
                }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}


double** ftnimag = new double* [log2(kn)]; // same goes for imaginary part
for (int i = 0; i < log2(kn); i++)
    ftnimag[i] = new double[kn];

for (int i = 0; i < log2(kn); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < kn; j++)
        ftnimag[i][j] = 0.0;
    if (i == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < kn/2; j++) {
            ftnimag[i][j * 2] = -sin(2 * M_PI * i / 2) * dm[2 * j + 1];
            ftnimag[i][j * 2 + 1] = sin(2 * M_PI * i / 2) * dm[2 * j + 1];
        }
    }
    else {
        tempval1 = pow(2, i + 1);
        tempval2 = pow(2, i);
        counter = 0;
        int tempvalcounter = 0;
        printf("i = %d, tempval1 = %d, tempval2 = %d\n", i, tempval1, tempval2);
        for (int j = 0; j < kn / 2; j++) {
            ftnimag[i][counter] = ftnimag[i - 1][counter] - sin(2 * M_PI * (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))) * ftnimag[i - 1][counter + tempval2];
            ftnimag[i][counter + tempval2] = ftnimag[i - 1][counter] + sin(2 * M_PI * (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))) * ftnimag[i - 1][counter + tempval2];
            printf("ftnreal[%d][%d] = ftnimag[%d][%d] - sin(2*%f*(%f/%f))*ftnreal[%d][%d]       / %f     %f\n", i, counter, i - 1, counter, M_PI, float(tempvalcounter), float(tempval1), i - 1, counter + tempval2, float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1), -sin(2*M_PI* (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))));
            printf("ftnreal[%d][%d] = ftnimag[%d][%d] + sin(2*%f*(%f/%f))*ftnreal[%d][%d]       / %f    %f\n", i, counter + tempval2, i - 1, counter,M_PI, float(tempvalcounter), float(tempval1), i - 1, counter + tempval2, float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1), sin(2*M_PI* (float(tempvalcounter) / float(tempval1))));
            counter++;
            tempvalcounter++;
            if (tempvalcounter % tempval2 == 0) {
                counter = counter + tempval2;
                tempvalcounter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
printf("-----------------------------------------------------------Real--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

//printf("%d", selectcounter);
for (int i = 0; i < log2(kn); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < kn; j++) {
        cout << ftnreal[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

printf("-----------------------------------------------------------Imaginary--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

for (int i = 0; i < log2(kn); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < kn; j++) {
        cout << ftnimag[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

printf("-----------------------------------------------------------Abs--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

tempval1 = log2(kn) - 1;
printf("%d\n", tempval1);
float* ftnabs = (float*)malloc(kn * sizeof(float));
for (int i = 0; i < kn; i++) {
    ftnabs[i] = sqrt(ftnreal[tempval1][i] * ftnreal[tempval1][i] + ftnimag[tempval1][i] * ftnimag[tempval1][i]);
    cout << ftnabs[i] << " ";
    cout << 2 * ftnabs[i] / kn << " ";
}


is the question about maths or about coding? Are you sure the code is correct and this is about some numerical effect? Or are you trying to confirm that the code is correct? If it is the former, consider https://math.stackexchange.com/. In either case, more details would be good, eg did you verify the results with some other tool? Do other test cases yield expected results?

Do you understand the meaning of the term "aliasing" in reference to the FFT?

The “should be”, is that what other FFTs produce, or is that some assumption of yours?

@Cris Luengo These results are obtained with the use of library function fft() in Matlab and several fft online calculators like this one for example: https://scistatcalc.blogspot.com/2013/12/fft-calculator.html
